# Can LLBLGEN return a dictionary-like object of the data in a database?

Tags: c#, orm, llblgen

Can LLBLGEN return a dictionary, where each key is the primary key a row, and each value is an object representing the data of a row. For example

```
var customers = new EntityCollection<CustomerWebSalesSummaryEntity>();
            using (var adapter = new DataAccessAdapter(config.ProductionConnectionString))
            {

                adapter.FetchEntityCollection(customers, null);
            }
```

My understanding is that `customers` is a list. I would like it to be a dictionary, where each key is the primary key of a customer row, and each value is an object representing the data of a customer row. I know that I can convert the list to a dictionary, but I was wondering if LLBLGEN had the option of returning one from the outset.

Comment: Does https://www.llblgen.com/documentation/5.1/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Adapter/gencode_usingcollectionclasses_adapter.htm help?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't help. I had already read that page before posting this question. The only thing in there that could remotely relate to my question is the section about  "Hierarchical projections of entity collections".  Skimming though it, it doesn't appear to give me what I want.

Comment: It's not a list, it's an entityCollection. Just use LINQ .ToDictionary().. It will do what you need.

Comment: The short answer is No, LLBLGen returns an EntityCollection<T> where T is a strongly typed object.